# How to trigger a save as dialog in the browser to so that in memory json data can be saved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, export, fullcalendar

Just like the title says, I need to save json in memory data. I want to be able to trigger this from onlick event on some dom object.

I want to save the data on the users computer as if they were downloading this file. Saving as text is fine.

There is no server to talk to.

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/adouga/GpcAt/1/

I am getting

`TypeError: cyclic object value
var json1 = JSON.stringify(mydata);`

**UPDATE:**
The cyclic error was happening because fullcalendar objects have it's own custom properties and nested objects. So I iterate over the returned object array and copy objects only with my properties to another array which can be stringified just fine

http://jsfiddle.net/adouga/GpcAt/2/

I think this might do the trick of copying to clipboard.

http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Comment: In memory where? on the users computer? You can probably do that with a cookie or local storage, but you'll have to convert your json to a string first. A little more information about what it is you are trying to do, how you intend to use it, and what you have tried so far would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

To save in the browser you can just use localStorage. To serve the json as text you can do with HTML5 File API. Check this discusion: [Create Text file from String using JS and html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654971/create-text-file-from-string-using-js-and-html5)

Comment: I'll try the solution in the link and let you know.

Comment: I am getting WebKitBlobBuilder is undefined. I guess IE8 does not support this.

Comment: IE does not support File API. To serve this file crossbrowser, you should use a server side solution.

Comment: I can just save the json data as a string into some hidden text area and then do a copy to clipboard. It's just text after all.

Comment: So just use JSON.stringify(json) and localStorage.setItem('myJsonKey' myjson)