# How to convert string to File object in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, file, type-conversion, readfile

I am trying to convert string to File object in javascript but I get an error.

my code:

```
 var contents = fs.readFileSync('./dmv_file_reader.txt').toString()

 var  readerfile1 = new File([""], contents);
```

(i have to use contents as file and not as string)

and my output is :

```
ReferenceError: File is not defined
    at d:\Workspace\DMV\dist\win-ia32-unpacked\resources\app.asar\main.js:67:32
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

any solution some1?

Comment: Seems that the `File` object is not defined... Might have to require something from a module?

Comment: There is no `File` object in node (assuming this is node since you're using `fs`). What are you trying to do with the file?

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript            ; Have you tried using the blob?

Comment: maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654971/create-text-file-from-string-using-js-and-html5

Comment: In my code i have this line:
`code reader.readAsArrayBuffer(changeEvent.target.files[0]); code`
and then i send it to a function that get 'ArrayBuffer'.
as i see here this function convert 'File' to 'ArrayBuffer'.
therefor i want to convert my 'String' to 'File' and then use this function above.

Comment: Which browser? version?

Comment: desktop application (using electron)

Answer (score 16):

First you have to create blob from Javascript object and that blob object can be passed to File() constructor to create a File Object.Hope this helps.

```
 var contents = fs.readFileSync('./dmv_file_reader.txt').toString()
 var blob = new Blob([contents], { type: 'text/plain' });
 var file = new File([blob], "foo.txt", {type: "text/plain"});
```

Comment: I think you can go straight to file by just having 'contents' where 'blob' is.